# Android: How to show my custom view over my MapActivity without xml?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, mapactivity

I have some small graphs on display over mapactivity. And when one of these graphs are clicked want to show up detailed graph with transparency over the google map.
 So I have class "myCusomGraphView extends View{...}" and I want to display it over MapActivity when it needed.

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry but i think here is nothing to post. I do not know how to make it without defining my custom view in xml mapactivity file :(

Answer (score 0):

Look into using [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). Or if you don't want that, use [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check it out and post the result here